# C# excel set width column in centimeters / pixel

Tags: c#, excel, width, pixel

I need to set excel width of column in centimeters or pixels via C# because Excel unit for width is big mystery for me. How do it work? I need to change columns width dynamically so that always my data were in A4 format.

this.excel.Application.CentimetersToPoints works only for height but width use totaly different unit of distance. It is horrible for me.

I set columns width this way (e.g.):

```
workSheet.get_Range(A1, A5).ColumnWidth = 1.5;
```

I tried to create own model for convert centimeter to column width but I only found out that column width is big mystery. I manually set column width from 1 to 10 and then I checked this values in centimeters in Excel. Here is result table:

```
Excel width: 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
Centimeters: 0.36 0,55 0.76 0.95 1.14 1.35 1.55 1.76 1.95 2.14
```

Difference between 1 - 2 is 0.19 cm

Difference between 2 - 3 is 0.21 cm

Difference between 9 - 10 is AGAIN 0.19 cm ?????????

It's chaos. Please help.

Comment: Does https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-column-width-and-row-height-72f5e3cc-994d-43e8-ae58-9774a0905f46 help?

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now I understand how it work and what is unit of column width in Excel but I still haven't known how to set column width by C# so that my data were ready for print in A4 page format.